# Hangfire "JobStorage.current" Property Failing to Initialize?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, ssms, hangfire

we're new to hangfire and trying to get it running. We're using an old ASP.net build with a global.asax file instead of a startup file.   We have two different environments, dev and staging.

The code is identical, *except for the connection string for the hangfire sql database, as it is located on a different server*.  Everything works great in Dev. The tables get created, the jobs run.  But when we migrated everything over to staging, we're getting the following error, and the Hangfire tables fail to create:

**JobStorage.Current property value has not been initialized. You must set it before using Hangfire Client or Server API**

Like I said, everything works fine in our dev environment, but in staging we get that error and the tables also fail to create. I'll still include the code for reference. I'm assuming it's an issue connection to the database or something with permissions? Can anyone that understands this error elaborate on that at all?

```
    private IEnumerable<IDisposable> GetHangfireServers()
    {
        _kernel = new StandardKernel(new PartnerIntegrationServiceNinjectModule());
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                           .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
                           .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
                           .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
                           .UseSqlServerStorage(_kernel.Get<ISettings>().HangfireConnectionString, new SqlServerStorageOptions
                           {
                               CommandBatchMaxTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                               SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                               QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.Zero,
                               UseRecommendedIsolationLevel = true,
                               DisableGlobalLocks = true,
                               SchemaName = "Hangfire"
                           }) ;

        yield return new BackgroundJobServer();
    }

    protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
    {
        base.OnApplicationStarted();

        HangfireAspNet.Use(GetHangfireServers);
```

Comment: You mentioned, `tables also fail to create`, have you checked firewalls or anything else blocking 1433 port from your staging server to your SQL server? also, make sure connection string is valid and has the proper credentials. If you use integrated security, ensure the service account you run the app under has permissions to SQL DB (to create and read)

Comment: I manually had our DBA team create the tables with the sql query included in the nuget package, but we are still getting that error... the service account has permission to read, not create, but now that the tables are created that shouldnt be an issue. s

Comment: For troubleshooting purposes, I would recommend letting hangfire service create the tables in a test DB and compare the tables it needs (along with the structure). Either you are missing a table or your access to the table is not correct.

Comment: Comparing it to the dev server, the tables look identical. I'm not sure if there are settings we have to use to tell Hangfire that the tables willl already be created?  The connection string to the DB is correct. I'm honestly lost as to where to go next.